# Gravitational waves from a time irreversible source?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, reversibility

So during the formation of a blackhole/particular phase transitions we have a time irreversible process occuring. How does one model the gravitational waves for such discontinuities in general relativity.

Comment: It doesn't tell me about the explicit modelling of the gravitational waves that would be associated with such a process

Comment: I mean there is a comment " My impression, mostly from work by Nikodem J. Poplawski visible on Arxiv, is that the gravitational time distorsion within the BH" ... But an explicit answer would be nice

Comment: Just realised even  a phase transition is an irreversible discontinuity: https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.3070

Comment: googling, I find that under certain conditions there could be reversible phase transitions, but I do not think  the dynamics of gravitational black holes allow it ( white holes would come in  I think)